# How to add fast Text to Speech to TensorFlow Lite Object Detection script on Raspberry Pi without slowing down the FPS?

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to this forum and I only know basic coding so sorry in advance if I'm unclear about anything. I'm trying to run object recognition on a live video feed from a picamera, which is connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 running Buster. I'm running Tensorflow Lite Object detection model because it has a faster frame rate. I followed EdjeElectronics' GitHub tutorial [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi) and successfully ran the TFLite_detection_webcam.py script with no problem. I was able to get an FPS of 4.6 to 4.8, which I'm really happy with. However, I wanted to add a speech output to the model so the Pi will tell me what object is being recognized. To do this, I used espeak as my text to speech engine in the model. I was able to get the text to speech working, but it causes the FPS to drastically drop to like 0.2 FPS. Obviously I would like it to be at least 4 FPS from before, however, I don't know how to change the code. The code block is here below(code is from EdjeElectronics) and the text to speech code is on the last few lines. The line I added is: `call(["espeak", object_name])  #object_name is the name of the object being recognized and changes when a new object is recognized` .  If someone has any advice to help me add text to speech to the script without slowing the detection speed/FPS down, I would greatly appreciate it. Or if you have any helpful suggestions like using a faster, lightweight text to speech engines like Festival or any ideas on how to change the code, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
 # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):

        # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
        # Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
        ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
        xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
        ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
        xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
        
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)

        # Draw label
        object_name = labels[int(classes[i])] # Look up object name from "labels" array using class index
        label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) # Example: 'person: 72%'
        labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) # Get font size
        label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10) # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) # Draw white box to put label text in
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) # Draw label text
        call(["espeak", object_name])
```

Comment: Just a comment because I don't write Python everyday. I'm thinking you want `Popen` instead of `call`, because `call` will wait for the espeak executable to complete, whereas `Popen` should just call the external program as a new process and forget about it (may not have thread safety). Also consider only calling espeak every X iteration, i.e. `if (i % 10 == 0): call(["espeak", object_name).`